# In terms of performance and user experience, which one is better Xamarin or Apache Cordova?

Tags: .net, cordova, xamarin, mobile-application

I am a .NET developer and I am excited that it is going open source.
Targeting multiple mobile devices and re-using some of the codes is a big plus for me.
I am happy that both Xamarin and Apache Cordova can offer [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Connect-event-2014/511).

For those in the industry who have been able to use both of these technology, which one has the better performance (when the app is deployed) and provides better user experience?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For Me Xamarin. I have used both but I prefer Xamarin seems to be more user friendly and I have never had a Performance problem with it. I have had a few hiccups with Apache Cordova but nothing to bad. I'm sure different people have different opinions on ether but that's my 2 cents.

Good Luck,
          Mark